# nsmenuadapter cannot be resolved as a type

Tags: android, eclipse, navigation-drawer

so i just start on developing android program, i'm not really good with java and i don't know what i am gonna do, so i just pick some random tutorial on internet and end up doing the navigation drawer project on this link :
http://gmariotti.blogspot.com/2013/05/creating-navigation-drawer.html

the problem is when i reach this part, i don't know what to do, i tried to find out what the problem is, but it seems i couldn't find the correct answer

```html
@Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_drawer);
       _initMenu();

   }

   private void _initMenu() {
       NsMenuAdapter mAdapter = new NsMenuAdapter(this);

        // Add Header
        mAdapter.addHeader(R.string.ns_menu_main_header);
        .....
        mAdapter.addItem(mItem);
 
 
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        if (mDrawerList != null)
            mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
   
  }
```

the problem is at the NsMenuAdapter, it is said cannot be resolved to a type

so please, could anyone explain it to me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own adapter class with the name of: NsMenuAdapter. This class will be responsible for displaying items in the list. More information: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html